# 3D coordinates extraction with 2 orthogonal cameras

Tags: c++, opencv, 3d

I'm implementing a software in c++/OpenCV that is able to track the 3D coordinates of a moving object wrt to a fixed reference system. I'm using a set of two orthogonal cameras that detect some colored markers placed onto my object.
Up to now the SW is able to detect the 2D image coordinates (in pixels) of my markers in both views, and I'd like to obtain their 3D coordinates in mm. I know the internal parameters and the external parameters (pose) of both cameras wrt my reference system.

I've already tried to implement the collinearity equations of motion, but the results are not correct.

Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance and have a nice day.

EDIT:

[image: collinearity equations]

where: 
`x, y` --> pixel coordinates of object in the first camera 
`x2, y2` --> pixel coordinates of object in the second camera 
`K1_side,  K2_side,  K1_bottom,  K2_bottom` --> parameters for the equations 
`Z_green,  Y_green,  X_green` --> 3D coordinates of the object wrt the ref system

This is just the part that implements the collinearity equations from scratch and by using the built in function `triangulatePoints` (commented).

Comment: Show us the code for what you've tried.

Comment: post code as code instead of image ...  1. is your detection of markers OK? render overlay to see if they match. 2. what do you mean by collinearity? you need to convert the marker position to 3D ray (based on camera FOV , pixel position and camera transform matrix) for each camera and compute intersection of the 2 rays in global coordinate system. The intersection is your 3D position of the marker